# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xmemory': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was having troubles with visual studio, and I ran a repair.  Upon my first compile, this error shows up.  Should I really just start from scratch or is there a fix?  I can't find any solution to this online...

Comment: Please post a minimal complete program (a [sscce](http://sscce.org)) which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I had a weird issue with Visual Studio 11 Dev preview too - suddenly the devenv.exe wasn't a valid executable file any more. Maybe something's just bogus with the preview... In any case, reinstalling should fix it.

Comment: Are you getting this error in all your solutions / projects? Why do you think that problem is in Visual Studio and not in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.  I know it's not the most interesting answer, but I just uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

It must be looking for that file in your directory structure. Find out where that file should be . Actually you Will see that file is missing from its expected location .You can copy that file , Which is requirement here for for Compilation . If you do so compilation will proceed further.